# Inserting bold characters in docusign text data tag

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to insert bold characters in a text data tag on my Docusign template.
I have tried many different ways of bolding characters (`<b>`, `<em>`, `<strong>`, `<h1>`, `<h2>`, `<h3>`, `**`) but none of these succeed.
I am aware that I can set the data field to be bold but I only want some of the data to be affected and splitting up my data to have bold and non-bold areas would make the template chaotic and difficult to maintain.
Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

DocuSign does not support partial formatting of Text tags. The formatting options available are for the the entire tag.

From [Documentation](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-field-properties)

> **Formatting** - defines the font family, size, and color, and character styling; for text fields, there is an additional formatting property to hide the text entered with asterisks, concealing the data from anyone else viewing the document.